# Iterating over df column list and replacing existing keys with their values from a dictionary efficiently python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, processing-efficiency

I have a dict with items probabilities.
I have a df with 5 milion rows that looks like that:

```
user_id   item_list
 U1       [I1,I3,I4]
 U2       [I5,I4]
```

and a dict: `{'I1': 0.1, 'I4': 0.4, ..}`

I am trying to go each row and creat a list with probailities, like that:

```
user_id   item_list     prob_list
 U1       [I1,I3,I4]    [0.1,0.4]
 U2       [I5,I4]       [0.4]
```

- not all items have probabilities.

This is my code:

```
keys = list(prob_dict.keys())
df['prob_list'] = df.progress_apply(lambda x: get_probability(prob_dict=prob_dict,
keys=keys, item_list=x['item_list']),axis=1)

def get_probability(prob_dict, keys, item_list):


    prob_list = []
    for item in item_list:
        if item  in keys:
           prob = prob_dict[item ]
           prob_list.append(prob)

    if len(prob_list)>=1:
        return prob_list
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Since I am using tqdm I know how long its going to take (120 hours), which is too much and it's clearly not efficient.

Any ideas on how I can do it more efficently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) to transform each item in `item_list` to pandas Series and correspondingly map this series using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to a mapping dictionary `d`, then use `dropna` to drop the `NaN` values:

```
d = {'I1': 0.1, 'I4': 0.4}

df['prob_list'] = (
    df['item_list'].transform(lambda s: pd.Series(s).map(d).dropna().values)
)
```

---

**UPDATE** (Use `multiprocessing` to improve the speed of mapping the `item_list` to `prob_list`):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def map_prob(s):
    s = s[~s.isna()]
    return s.transform(
        lambda lst: [d[k] for k in lst if k in d] or np.nan)

def parallel_map(item_list):
    splits = np.array_split(item_list, mp.cpu_count())
    pool = mp.Pool()
    prob_list = pd.concat(pool.map(map_prob, splits))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return prob_list

df['prob_list'] = parallel_map(df['item_list'])
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
  uer_id     item_list   prob_list
0     U1  [I1, I3, I4]  [0.1, 0.4]
1     U2      [I5, I4]       [0.4]
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it, does it counts for items that are not in the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it does, the items which are not in dictionary will not appear in the output.

Comment: @anat Check the updated answer, I've made few changes.

Comment: I just tried it on 100 rows out of the 5.6M and its been few minutes and it didnt finish yet..

Comment: @anat As a matter of fact this should take time, because you have iterate over all the values in the column to map them from dictionary. May be you can speed things up by using multiprocessing.

Comment: I know it a lot but I dont have 200 hours, is there a way to know how long this code will take? what kind of multiprocessing I can do in that case?

Comment: It takes exactly 1 min to go over 100 rows, so its going to take more than 120 hours. It seems like my code is more efficent.

Comment: @anat wait, till tomorrow, it's just sleeping time for me, I will edit the answer with multiprocessing solution first thing in the morning.

Comment: Thank you, but since my code is faster can you add to it instead?

Comment: Thank you very much, from what I can tell it takes 17 sec on 1000 rows so its amazing. Thank you again!

Comment: @anat Glad I could help :).

Comment: can you also help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129477/paralle-apply-function-on-df-in-python

Comment: How do I change it to account for np.nan in the rows? (some rows doesnt have item_list)

Comment: @anat added the condition to account for NaN values in `item_list` column.